# Can I use Crystal Reports on MonoDevelop?

Tags: development, monodevelop

I would like to know if I can use Crystal Reports in MonoDevelop. I have a project that was developed in Visual Basic .Net (Windows) and this project is using Crystal Report, so I'd like to use this project in MonoDevelop on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 0):

There's a project called MonoReports, which can be [found on Github](https://github.com/MonoReports/MonoReports). I've not used it myself, but the README looks promising

> Monoreports is a cross-platform (linux/win/mac) report designer and
>   reporting engine for .net/mono It's similar to the CrystalReport (TM)
>   and other tools like that.

I'm not sure if you'll be able to port a CrystalReports project to MonoReports. From what I've read, it doesn't seem possible. I would suggest making a backup of you project and then attempting to open it with MonoReports and see what happens.